# Is there a way of knowing how many installs my app currently have?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Am I missing something?? Android developers get this information easily, but iTunes connect provides (as far as I know) only numbers on downloaded and updated units.
 I'm not sure if the "downloaded" number is the absolute number of downloads (not including deleted units).

Is there a way if knowing the current number of installs of a certain build? (Or deleted number of units).

Thanks,

Comment: No, but there will be in the next revision of iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate analytics in your app. The best is Flurry. Flurry shows you all kinds of things from total installs, installs of different versions, age estimates, gender estimates, frequency of use etc etc.

Flurry is free and to integrate it, follow instructions on the flurry website: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks, i know flurry. Was just wandering about itunes connect ;)